# rspec not calling 'to_json' implicitly on 'render(json: @instance)'

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, rspec, render, rspec-rails

I am not certain this is a direct rspec error but when testing a controller action, we expect our response to be a json object of the instance we are getting. What we receive though is a json object of

```
=> render(json: @instance)
"{\"type\":\"class_name\"}"
```

If I manually call '.to_json' on my instance at the point of render

```
=> render(json: @instance.to_json)
<full object json response>
```

I get a full response back of my whole object, which is the expected behaviour and is matched with development and production environments.

I can't see a reason why the implicit 'to_json' is not called when calling from rspec which is stated in the rails docs

[image: rails guide]

Any help is greatly appreciated. TIA

**Edit**

The controller action

```
def show
  render(json: @book)
end
```

book_controller_spec.rb
'json' is a custom JSONHelper which just parses the response.body

```rb
RSpec.describe(Api::V1::BooksController, type: :controller) do
  before :each do
    create(:book)
  end

  context '#show' do
    it 'returns the book with the correct ID' do
      get :show, params: { id: 1 }
      puts response.body
      json_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
      expect(json_response[:id]).to(eq(1))
    end
  end
end
```

Response

```
{"type":"book"}
```

## UPDATE:

I noticed that the object wasn't being serialized when adding then .to_json method and I wondered if active model serializers may be causing an issue. I forced the method to use the matching serializer 'BookSerializer' and this worked without .to_json. I then removed the ams gem and it failed, hitting the ApplicationSerializer and this is where I believe the "{"type":"book"}" response is coming from. It still does not explain why the proper serializer is not being used.

ApplicationSerializer

```rb
class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :type

  def type
    object.class.name.downcase
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code (e.g. the test and the controller action it is testing?)

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: 1) Could you show us the code for `json`? 2) Check `response.body`. 3) What is the actual test failure?

Comment: 1) JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
2) "{\"type\":\"class_name\"}"
3) I'm not concerned about the test failure as we aren't able to get an object back to test yet. It should return a full object back with id, name etc etc but we only get the response as per question 2

Comment: For the purposes of this question I would suggest replacing the `json` function, it's opaque to us, with the JSON parsing, a clear test, and the test result. I would also `p @book` in the controller just to be sure.

Comment: I have added the additional context

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. `p @book` in the controller. Is there anything peculiar about your Book model? Note that you never create a Book for the test. How are you getting `@book` and how does the test know the ID is 1?

Comment: more context added. 
book is created in a before each block. Book definitely exists. As I said, issue appears to be at the render stage or the response is being interpreted somewhere else.

Comment: i tried it with active_model_serializers `v0.10.13`. the way implicit to_json happens is like this: `Api::V1::BooksController.new.get_serializer(Book.first).to_json`. maybe `get_serializer` output can help, you should have `Book` and `BookSerializer` there.

Comment: Thank you Alex, this has helped me solve the issue. 
Turns out a rogue dev added a nested folder structure for only this controllers serializer and it was empty. Hence giving back just the values from the ApplicationSerializer... he has been scolded

Comment: please mark it at solved then ✌️

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest editing your test to request a JSON response. I searched more about the problem; setting the request headers on RSpec can be tricky. You can do the following though.

```
  it 'forces a JSON response' do
    get :show, params: { id: 1 }, format: :json
  end
```

Comment: I will try your codes as stated but am fairly certain this was attempted at some stage. I’ll revert back with results 

Comment: I tried your answer Christos but unfortunately it doesn't make any difference to the response. 
Also, just an FYI, 'headers' is not an accepted parameter.. think this may be related to versions of rspec-rails but not entirely sure. 
I wrote your code like so in order to get the headers accepted. I checked these in the request and they definitely come through but no change to the response
```
headers = { ACCEPT: 'application/json', 'CONTENT-TYPE': 'application/json' }
      request.headers.merge!(headers)
      get :show, params: { id: 1 }
```

Comment: @bubbaspaarx I updated my answer this should fix your problem. I also tested it and I can see on the logs that it calls the controller as a JSON action.

Comment: I have tried this code too now but still getting the same issue. The response was already in JSON format so this wasn't the initial problem, but it's still not performing the .to_json on the object before returning it. 

Also, we had to adapt the code for Rails 6 so it's
get :show, params: { id: 1, format: :json }